# can we invoke any activty or service on android wear using voice command

Tags: android, wear-os

i know that i can start my application launcher activity in wear by invoking voice command (Eg Start MyApp) right from wear home screen but i want to invoke other activities with the same mechanism i.e  using voice command for example start B where B is the name of my activity other than launcher activity.i want to launch the Activty B  from the Wear home screen itself and not opening via my application .Similar as in case of application launcher activity can be launched from Wear home screen.Does android wear support this feature?Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);    
        voiceIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        startActivityForResult(voiceIntent,SPEECH_RECOGNIZER_CODE);
        }
```

Start the activity as shown above , it'll open a default google voice listening dialogue box.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   try { if (requestCode == SPEECH_RECOGNIZER_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            String spokenText = results.get(0);
       }
```

Implement the above mentioned method in your activity. By matching the string "spokenText" to the Activity name you can start that activity.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but my problem here is that i want to launch the second activity from the Wear home screen itself and not opening  via my application .Similar as in case of application launcher activity can be launched from Wear home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Will the activity which you vocally invoke change time to time or it's the second activity always ?

Comment: Its same activty always.Requirement is to invoke a invoke a particular activity in my app  from wear home screen without invoking launcher activity.Lets say there is a feature called start calculation in my app present in my app on second activity and i want  to launch that acitivity without launching application using voice command from android wear home screen

Answer (score 0):

Well I can think of a crude fix, i assume that you have added "android:label" to your launcher activity so that the app is invoked by the voice command from the wear home screen.Add the label Value as "secondactivity"(Or the activity name you want to invoke - so that the user can use it without having to worry about the app name). Is it a problem if you finish the launcher activity in OnCreate method itself and open the second activity from there on ? Just my thoughts.

Comment: Thatz precisely my query,i had already added ""android:label" to my launcher activity.Can i do the same with another activity so that it can also be launched the same way by voice command from wear home screen.

Comment: I don't think that will work but you can try this as i mentioned earlier , set the label value as "second activity" , for the launcher activity in the manifest, so that the user will be able to call the second activity verbally. Let the control come to "onCreate" of launcher activity, finish the activity there itself and call the second activity from there. That solves your problem.